# Vega-Lite json code for creating a World Heat Map

Tags: json, visualization, heatmap, vega-lite

I decided to create a visualization using Vega-Lite. I am faily new at it, so I don't really know how to solve this problem.
My code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 400,
  "data": {
    "url": "world-110m.json",
    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "countries"}
  },
      "transform": [
        {
        "lookup": "id",
        "from": {
          "data": {
            "url": "new_food_consumption.csv"
          },
          "key": "id",
          "fields": ["co2_emmission", "country", "food_category"]
        }
      },
      {
        "filter": {"field": "food_category", "equal": "beef"}
      }
    ],

      "projection": {
        "type": "mercator"
      },
      "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "stroke": "black"},
      "encoding": {
        
        "color": {
          "field": "co2_emmission",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"range": ["blue", "red"]}
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "co2_emmission", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "country", "type": "nominal"},
          {"field": "food_category", "type": "nominal"}
        ]
      }
    

}
```

The issue is that I cannot make this map interactable. Anything I try to change will completely remove the map.

CSV has multiple of the same country fields with different co2 emissions which I wanted to sum to create one value for co2, so I decided to perform aggregation and it did not work well with the code. Another problem was also when I tried to filter by one field, which also removed the map. Is there a better way of making the world map heat map?
(All of my files are on my drive since the actual map link doesn't work, and I had to add IDs to the online csv)

An example for the csv file:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| id | country | food_category | consumption | co2_emmission |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 32 |Argentina|     Pork      |    10.51    |     37.2      |
| 32 |Argentina|    Poultry    |    38.66    |     41.53     |
| 32 |Argentina|     Beef      |    55.48    |   1712.0      |
| 36 |Australia|     Pork      |    24.14    |85.44000000000001|
| 36 |Australia|    Poultry    |46.120000000000005|49.54     |
| 36 |Australia|     Beef      |    33.86    |   1044.85     |
|                              ...                           |
| 430| Liberia |     Pork      |     4.01    |     14.19     |
| 430| Liberia |    Poultry    |     8.91    |      9.57     |
| 430| Liberia |     Beef      |0.7799999999999999|24.07     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please provide an example where we have access to "new_food_consumption.csv"